# Getting total SUM from has many

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two tables where I'm trying to figure out a way to get the SUM of the Ordered column in the Order table, when querying the Product table and show it for each individual product.

This is how I get all products currently and I would like to expand this to calculate the fields while querying or if possible using the generated columns function of PostgreSQL. Thought I'm unsure if it can be used in this case with Foreign Keys.

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Orders      []Order `gorm:"ForeignKey:ProductID" json:"orders"`
}

type Order struct {
    gorm.Model
    ProductID   uint   `json:"productID"`
    Ordered     int8   `gorm:"default:0" json:"ordered"`
}


func GetProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var products []Product
    db.Preload("Orders").Find(&products)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(products)
}
```

I think the SQL query is something along these lines (don't know much SQL)

```
select *, ( select sum(ordered) from orders where product_id = products.id) ordered from products;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the following.

```
func GetProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var products []Product
    subQuery := db.Select("SUM(ordered) as ordered").Where("product_id = products.ID").Table("orders")
    db.Select("*, (?)", subQuery).Preload("Orders").Find(&products)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(products)
}
```